# css: shrinking images leave wide white margins on right

Tags: javascript, html, css

Update: the problem is in javascript.  See comment at below

My website ([Link](http://sdhematopathology.org)) has 6 sliding images beneath the menu.  I want to shrink the sizes of these images from 600 x 300 to 400 x 200.  However, shrinking will leave wide white margins on the right side ([see the developing version](http://sdhematopathology.org/index_dev.php)).  In the css file, I looked at all the ul#images codes (see below) and could not figure out how to remove the white margins.  Thanks for your input:

```
/* Image Transitions */
ul#images {
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul#images li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 155px;  <!-- ?the portion shown initially-->
  height: 300px; <!-- -->
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your **css**, it is in the **javascript**, it is setting the other pictures to **66px** wide on mouse over, make this width larger to fill in the white space.

Post your **javascript** and I will gladly fix it for you.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I found the javascript code `$('#images').kwicks({
        max : 600,
        spacing : 4
      });`  After changing 600 to 400, the problem is solved.  Thanks!